# Avoid passing around the session everywhere

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

After reading SQLAlchemy documentation on how to better utilize sessions, I find myself passing the session around to all my class methods.
How can I still use context managers with sessions and avoid passing them everywhere? 
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html

instead of methods like

> def get_query_config(self, db):

I'd like to keep

> def get_query_config(self):

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean, but why don't you have a property in your class that is set to your session? Like `self.session`?

Comment: because I don't know if that could be used with a context manager?

Comment: If you don't know if the session is there, it's basically the same as saying that a variable changes its value and you don't want to pass the new value. If you want to make sure the session is there there's only two choices: either you always pass it, or the instance of the class dies with the context manager (which is almost the same because then you have to re-initialize with the new value)

Comment: It is not completely clear what you are doing in your case, but usually yes, you need to pass the session around.

Comment: @zvone, what happens if it is not passed around and just a property of the class as mentioned?

Comment: Storing the session in `self.session` is one way of passing it around, yes. But what happens then depends on what `self` is. You will want the session to live long enough for all that you need and yet not longer than that. For that purpose, it would be best to make it as clear as possible how long it lives.

Comment: Just store it as an attribute. Why dont you want to do that?

Comment: Of course `self.session` can be used as a context manager, context managers are a type of object, and `self.session` would reference that object in the same way as `session` for that purpose

Comment: One option: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html